# Django Model Structure for products with Multiple Categories

Tags: django, django-models, design-patterns, database-design, django-mptt

I want to know if it is possible (and if so, what is the most pythonic way) to have a product that belongs to multiple product categories. e.g. an avocado belonging to [Food->Fresh Food->Fruit & Vegetables->Salad & Herbs] as well [Food->Pantry->Global Cuisine->Mexican]?

I am currently using Django-MPTT to create the category tree for single-category products.
How do I set up the Product and Category models, what would the data import look like, and what would an efficient query look like?
I am open to any suggestion, even if it requires me to rewrite my project. I would appreciate ANY advice on anything to do with this problem.

I am currently using Django-MPTT to create the category tree for single-category products. It makes sense conceptually, but I'm struggling with the multiple-category tree.

I've found some [examples](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/mptt.fields/TreeManyToManyField/-/python-treemanytomanyfield-class-examples.html) of [TreeManyToManyField](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#treeforeignkey-treeonetoonefield-treemanytomanyfield)

```
class Category(MPTTModel, CreationModificationDateMixin):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            blank=True,
                            null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['tree_id', 'lft']
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'


class Product(CreationModificationDateMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = TreeManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'
```

but there are no explanations or examples of import/creating data for such a model.
I have also seen the following example of how to set up the Category model, but they use a BaseProduct which threw me off:

```
class CategoryProductBase(BaseProduct):
    main_category = TreeForeignKey(get_category_model_string('Category'))
    additional_categories = TreeManyToManyField(
        get_category_model_string('Category'),
        related_name='extra_product_categories')
```